# How to prevent repeated declaration of object in C++ in nested functions?

Tags: c++

Actually, this is problem that will let me make one intresting trick with nested lambda-expression.

Let's take a lambda that looks like this:

```
[]()
{
   static int a;
   ...
   return a;
}
```

That is fine, because static variable will be available in the function and even in lambda-functions that could have been nested inside of this. But what if I want to double the same lambda like this:

```
[]()
    {
       static int a;
       []()
       {
           static int a; //should be hidden because it has been declared outside
           ...
           return a;
       }
       return a;
    }
```

I don't wanna nested lambda declares static variable, because it has been already declared by first lambda. I know that I can use

```
#if defined(a)
```

But will be it right? I want to avoid declaration if a variable has been already declared before!

Comment: It seems like you need to capture `[a]` in the inner lambda if you want to use the outer `a`.  Are you saying you want code that works without capturing the outer `a` but lets you use it in the inner lambda?

Comment: There is no way to determine whether an identifier is in scope or not. Why not just use different names instead?

Comment: `#if defined(a)` checks whether a preprocessor item is defined, not a C++ variable.

Comment: Also, the second `a` is not a re declaration, it is shadowing the outer variable, thus declaring/instantiating a completely different variable.

Comment: Could you tell use what's the purpose of all of this? If you do, someone will probably show you a solution which doesn't use nested lambas and static ints.

Comment: Because I have special complier for one primitive language but I am not able to change general concept and try to use what I have now. The main point is that all functions in this language are translated in C++ lambdas and it works but problem is that nested function should not declare this variable if it has been declared outside